# React: Cannot replace the component inside render() method

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am building a simple question-answer game for practise, however having some issues on question change. The way I planned to handle the rendering questions one by one is to create a queue of questions inside an array as component state (PractiseScreen.prototype.state.questionQueue) and using an IntermediateRenderer component to pass the current question index as props and the question queue as it is, so it could render the correct question on parent component's state change. However, when I debug the  component, I do not see that the next question is rendered.

What is the issue in my code? Thanks in advance!

```
import React from 'react';
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
} from 'react-native';

import MyText from '../custom-components/MyText';
import Question from '../components/Question';

import entries from '../mockData/entries';

class IntermediateRenderer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (<React.Fragment>
      {this.props.allQuestionComponents[this.props.questionIndexToRenderNext]}
    </React.Fragment>)
  }
}

export default class PractiseScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currentQuestionIndex: 0,
      questionQueue: []
    }

    this.buildQuestionQueue = this.buildQuestionQueue.bind(this);
    this.goToNextQuestion = this.goToNextQuestion.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.buildQuestionQueue();
  }

  buildQuestionQueue() {
    const questionQueue = [];
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      questionQueue.push(<Question
        entry={entry}
        goToNextQuestion={this.goToNextQuestion}
      />)
    });
    this.setState({ questionQueue });
  }

  goToNextQuestion() {
    console.log('Go to next question request is received.');
    this.setState({ currentQuestionIndex: this.state.currentQuestionIndex + 1 }, () => {
      console.log('Current question index is now: ', this.state.currentQuestionIndex);
    })
  }

  render() {
    if(this.state.questionQueue !== 0) {
      return <React.Fragment>
        <IntermediateRenderer
          allQuestionComponents={this.state.questionQueue}
          questionIndexToRenderNext={this.state.currentQuestionIndex}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    } else {
      <View>
        <Text>
          Questions are loading.
        </Text>
      </View>
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is the prop "questionIndexToRenderNext" correctly counting up?

Comment: You missed a return statement in else in render PractiseScreen component

Comment: @AgMr this @Draconatis also has detected, but it is just the `return` statement of a question placeholder.

Comment: @Nino9612 when I `console.log(this.props.questionIndexToRenderNext)` inside the `componentDidUpdate` of IntermediateRenderer, I can see that it correctly counts up.

Comment: Can you show the code of Question component?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you just forgot return statement:

```
  render() {
    if(this.state.questionQueue !== 0) {
      return <React.Fragment>
        <IntermediateRenderer
          allQuestionComponents={this.state.questionQueue}
          questionIndexToRenderNext={this.state.currentQuestionIndex}
        />
      </React.Fragment>
    } else {
      return <View>
        <Text>
          Questions are loading.
        </Text>
      </View>;
    }
  }
```

It seems that it runs fine first time, but when you proceed with next question it fails on missing return statement and display nothing.

Comment: Hello, thanks for noticing, yet it doesn't seem to be the issue, since the missing `return` statement is only for question placeholder.

Comment: @UğurKaya any errors in console? Can't see any other issues.

Comment: I have done what I want to do in another way, so not a big deal anymore. But very weird that it didn't work.

Comment: how did you do it now?